# Connecting to ibmmq qm fails , channel name not recognized

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ibm-mq

issue: connecting with spring boot to ibmmq , working ibmmq on dockor version 9.1.5-r2

in online environment: connecting is enabled ,all is fine.

in offline environment channel name is not recognized, getting channel unknown error - 'MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME'

channel name DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN

2 questions:

1. why offline is different and how it can be fixed?
2. connected to container with docker exec, how can i find the actual channel name of the queue manager.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "offline", but the channel name DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN is not created by default on queue managers (except those in the cloud I think). You need to define the SVRCONN, or use the MQSC command DISPLAY CHANNEL to find the name of one that is already defined.

Comment: offline meaning no internet connection. and run the container from local image file.
connecting by docker exec to the mq, DISPLAY CHANNEL -> command not found.
as i understand this image is creating this channel , as mentioned it is working fine on another environment (connected to internet, might not be related).
thanks.

Comment: Are you saying it is the exact same container, created with the same scripts?

Comment: Created the same way by docker desktop

Comment: Can you update your question details with the scripts used, specifically the MQSC script used to pre-created the various objects on the queue manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the channel name:

- shell into the container
- set the environment by running
  `setmqenv`
  See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=reference-setmqenv-set-mq-environment
- run `runmqsc`
- In the `runmqsc` prompt run
  `display channel (*)`
  See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=reference-display-channel-display-channel-definition

Alternatively, you could just log into the MQ Console on https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/console
and list the system  channels.

If you are using the IBM MQ Advanced for Developers image from `icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest` then the channels `DEV.APP.SVRCONN` and `DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN` will have been created for you. Apps will normally use `DEV.APP.SVRCONN`

If you have built the image locally based on instructions from https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/docs/building.md then you need to have run `make build-devserver`. If you ran `make build-advancedserver` then the default `DEV` channels will not have been created.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. still not solved, solution got closer.